# What is the easiest way to generate a Lucene.NET synonym list XML?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

What is the easiest way to generate a synonym list XML for use in Lucene.NET? From what I've read, Lucene.NET will load an XML document such as this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<synonyms>
<group>
    <syn>fast</syn>
    <syn>quick</syn>
    <syn>rapid</syn>
</group>

<group>
    <syn>slow</syn>
    <syn>decrease</syn>
</group>

<group>
    <syn>google</syn>
    <syn>search</syn>
</group>

<group>
    <syn>check</syn>
    <syn>lookup</syn>
    <syn>look</syn>
</group>
</synonyms>
```

I've tried search for a tool that would take say a CSV and spit out an XML document in the correct format.  However, I was surprised not to find anything.  So either my understanding is incorrect and an XML document like the above isn't the way to load synonyms in Lucene.net, or I'm not searching correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read Simon's answer. Lucene.Net is a pure indexing & searching engine and doesn't have to ability to parse xml, doc, xls  etc. files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml comes from a CodeProject article, [Lucene.Net - Custom Synonym Analyzer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32201/Lucene-Net-Custom-Synonym-Analyzer), which also includes a `XmlSynonymEngine` to parse your xml. You could build a custom `ISynonymEngine` to parse your csv data directly without converting your input to xml.